# What ways of calling methods give me the best performance

Tags: java, performance

What i want to ask is if i do

```
final Cat c = getBlackCat();
polishCat(c);
```

Or

```
polishCat(getBlackCat());
```

Are those compiled into the same thing ? Whats the best practice ? and what would be the memory wise and cpu wise better ?

Comment: Does `getBlackCat` return `final Cat`?

Comment: It looks like a matter of style/opinion. I believe your compiler should make the optimizations automatically. In my opinion the first style is easier to read, and debug.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, no. its not guaranteed to be final

Comment: Then they're not the same.

Comment: From a memory perspective, its totally the same, but the from the code readability the first one is more preferable.

Comment: @MarounMaroun This is Java, not C. The only thing "final" signifies is that the REFERENCE cannot be changed. A method can't choose whether it returns a "Cat" or a "final Cat". It will always return an immutable reference to a Cat object.

Comment: @Malt I was referring "are those compiled into the same thing", not I have doubts, will check that.

Comment: I like the second example better, imho, it's more readable (as a reader, I know that I don't need the cat later in the code - I only want to polish my black cat). And I can't see a problem when debugging this.

Comment: @malt Calling the reference "immutable" is odd because it's just a *value*, an abstract bit pattern. It's immutable by its very nature, just like 1 is immutable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik there's nothing odd about calling the reference "immutable", it has nothing to do with its abstractness. An immutable reference cannot be modified, that's it.

Comment: @malt The point: there is no such thing as a *mutable reference* because that's an oxymoron. So saying "reference, which is immutable by nature" passes muster, but "an immutable reference" does not because it would require us to change what "reference" means in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bytecode level, you must always explictly store the result of one method invocation to be able to feed it into the next one. You can consider the "nested calls" idiom in Java as just syntactic sugar over that. So yes, the two pieces of code are equivalent.

Which is preferred stylistically is open to debate and there are arguments in favor of either. I favor the argument that each time you explicitly name a thing in your code, it creats an obligation on the part of the reader to remember that name and what it refers to. If the variable is not final then the reader must in addition carefully track all usages of the variable lest there be another assignment somewhere else, even if by accident (for example, using `=` instead of `==`). If you call methods inline, you don't impose that cognitive load.

Comment: The first one requires storing, then loading. The second one just pushes the result of `getBlackCat()` on the stack and calls the next method.

Comment: No, it does not require any such thing. Local variables are just names for particular results, they do not entail any load and store operations on their own. Perhaps a very non-optimizing compiler might issue such machine code, but that is not because it was *required* to do so.